# Move documents from SQL database to file system

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, document, sql-server, file-system

I have a SQL database server for the SharePoint 2013 on-premise site. The amount of BLOB data is huge which is slowing down the SQL server and hampering system's performance. I want to migrate and store all BLOBs from content database to file system and give user read/write permission.

How can I do that? What are the challenges? Is there any negative impact of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

We suggest you use SharePoint Server together with Remote BLOB Storage (RBS) and SQL Server to optimize database storage resources.

More information for your reference:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/rbs-overview

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/install-and-configure-rbs

Comment: Microsoft's RBS has severe limitations (database + content cannot exceed 200GB) and was not designed for _performance_ but rather for the transition from WID to SQL Express. Do not use Microsoft's RBS as a performance 'solution'.

Comment: @TrevorSeward thanks for sharing